# How to resolve issues with a bar plot x-axis being overcrowded

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, time-series, bar-chart

Here's a Python program which does the following:

- Makes an API call to treasury.gov to retrieve data
- Stores the data in a Pandas dataframe
- Plots the data as a bar chart

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

date = '1900-01-01'

transaction_type = 'Withdrawals'
transaction_catg = 'Interest on Treasury Securities'

page_size = 10000

url = 'https://api.fiscaldata.treasury.gov/services/api/fiscal_service/v1/accounting/dts/deposits_withdrawals_operating_cash'

url_params = f'?filter=record_date:gt:{date},transaction_type:eq:{transaction_type},transaction_catg:eq:{transaction_catg}&page[size]={page_size}'

response = requests.get(url + url_params)

result_json = response.json()

df = pd.DataFrame(result_json['data'])

# Convert transaction_today_amt to numeric
df['transaction_today_amt'] = pd.to_numeric(df['transaction_today_amt']) 

df.plot.bar(x='record_date', y='transaction_today_amt')

plt.show()
```

Here's the resulting chart that I get:

[image]

As you can see, there are too many x-axis labels.

## Question

What's a good way to setup the chart so that the x-axis labels are legible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The `'record_date'` values are strings, not datetimes.

  - `df.record_date = pd.to_datetime(df.record_date)`
- Typically, a line plot should be used for continuous timeseries data.

#### Line Plot

```py
ax = df.plot(x='record_date', y='transaction_today_amt', figsize=(12, 7))
```

[image]

#### Scatter Plot

```py
ax = df.plot(kind='scatter', x='record_date', y='transaction_today_amt', marker='.', figsize=(12, 7))
```

[image]

#### Bar Plot

- Use [matplotlib](/questions/tagged/matplotlib) directly, because the xticks are datetime ordinals, which will label the x-axis with the Year.

  - `ax.get_xticks()` → `array([12418., 13149., 13879., 14610., 15340., 16071., 16801., 17532., 18262., 18993., 19723.])`

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 5), dpi=200)

ax.bar(x='record_date', height='transaction_today_amt', data=df)
ax.set_yscale('log')
```

[image]

- [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) treats the xticks as discrete, and plots all of them.

```py
ax = df.plot(kind='bar', x='record_date', y='transaction_today_amt', figsize=(12, 7))
```

[image]

Comment: @dharmatech 3916 our of 4538 records are <=10. They can be filtered out with `df = df[df.transaction_today_amt.gt(10)]`.

Comment: Good suggestion.  The chart is created much faster that way.

Comment: I've posted a related question on grouping here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77363957/using-grouper-to-group-dataframe-by-various-timeframes-and-charting